# Stop the jquery code on keypress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have this code that loads the php file in a div and it automatically reloads every 5 seconds. Here is the code

```
$("#load_timeout").load("time_out.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#load_timeout").load('time_out.php');
}, 5000);
```

This is my textbox `<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">`
Now what I wanted to do is to stop this code from running when I type any character from my textbox and if I clear out the textbox it will continue to execute/reload the php file again. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. It is simple, if your input text box value's length is 0 then execute the `load()` function. If it's greater than 0, then don't execute the `load()` function.

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/sdsa7s38/3/)  . open browser console and check .

```
$("#load_timeout").load("time_out.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    if($('.light-table-filter').val().length == 0){    
        $("#load_timeout").load('time_out.php');
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried your code and when the length of the textbox is not empty then it is not refreshing, however when the textbox is empty already it isn't refreshing anymore

Comment: @FewFlyBy have you used the right selector for `<input>`? This should work.

Comment: can you add html also .. and code you tried using my example?

Comment: This won't work if the user types in a value and then deletes everything in the textbox.

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdsa7s38/) console. This works. Its just that OP is not using the right selector I guess.

Comment: @jsve can you tel me why ? when textbox is clear its length is 0

Comment: @FewFlyBy check i update my answer with your input text-box selector